# Синонимизировать `mercurial` и `hg`

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, синонимы-меток

Предлагаю синонимизировать метки

- [mercurial](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mercurial) - 29 вопросов
- [hg](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hg) - 11 вопросов

С обеими метками - 9 вопросов

Основная метка - **mercurial**

Речь о системе контроля версий [Mercurial](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercurial)

Просто удалить метки **hg** из вопросов не вижу смысла, поскольку hg - это по сути и есть синоним mercurial, общепринятое сокращенное название и имя утилиты командной строки данной VCS - в любом случае кто-то попытается эту метку добавить.

Comment: Понятия не имею, как оно связано...

Comment: @Qwertiy, добавил в вопрос

Comment: @insolor думаю, можно закрывать (:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[hg](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hg) нужно синонимизировать к [mercurial](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mercurial). Я слабо себе представляю, в каком другом контексте [hg](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hg) может использоваться, кроме как в связке с [mercurial](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mercurial).

Answer (score 5):

Учитывая то, что на практике используется команда `hg` и GUI с названиями вроде TortoiseHg, **вопрошающие могут не знать названия самой VCS: *Mercurial***. Посему кроме синонимизации стоит отдельно отразить **в описании** [mercurial](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mercurial), что команда `hg` из неё.